# To what extent do different languages allow different understanding of reality?

Tags: grammar

I know that some languages have more or less tenses, have a more or less complete vocabulary, and in these ways it seems they would allow a native speaker a more or less accurate understanding of reality.

Is there any scale that compares languages in this way? And what are other features of languages that can be used to compare them in this way? What would be some of the top languages on such a scale?

Does learning multiple languages give a more accurate understanding of reality?

Comment: Can you specify more about what you think reality is? A lot of people think the subject that physics studies (and related science) is 'the' reality, and as universal as it is, it is communicated via many distinct human languages.

Comment: Fundamentally, things move and that's all. Everything else is emergent. Time is an illusion, there is no past or future. Most fields study one part of reality at one level or another. Physics studies reality, but so do biology and economics. I feel that as my understanding of English grammar improves, so does my understanding of reality, and this seems to have been catalyzed by my understanding of a second language.

Comment: @JimmySmith I'm a bit curious what you mean by "time is an illusion" if "things move and that's all". Movement means change over time. But also, how do verb tenses help you understand time if time is an illusion?

Comment: Before you can answer (or even ask coherently) whether different languages allow different understandings of reality, you have to be able to say whether different humans (irrespective of language, race, religion, culture, or whatnot) have different understandings of reality, and how you can tell. If language is affecting something, what exactly is it affecting?

Comment: Inaccurate definitions of words in each person's vocabulary both reflect and cause an inaccurate understanding of reality. @Draconis believes "movement" to mean "change over time", but I think movement is not related to time, although models of time can allow predictions of movement in relation to other movement. Our definitions of "movement" differ, so 1 of us has a less accurate understanding of reality, as a direct result of a less accurate understanding of 1 word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gets into the question of "linguistic determinism", also known as the "strong Sapir-Whorf hypothesis". It's arguably the single most controversial idea in linguistics. And as a disclaimer, I don't accept it.

Specifically, the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis was proposed by the linguist Benjamin Whorf (without any actual collaboration from Sapir), and now has two forms. The *weak* Sapir-Whorf hypothesis says that language *influences* the way we think, and the *strong* Sapir-Whorf hypothesis says that language *determines* the way we think. In other words, according to the strong version, we can't conceptualize something we have no words for.

There is, actually, some evidence for the weak form. Berlin and Kay's research on color words is the most famous and always comes up in these discussions: they showed that people do actually categorize colors differently based on their native language. English-speakers, who distinguish "pink" and "red" on a fundamental level, will be good at telling the difference between shades of red/pink. On the other hand, English doesn't distinguish light and dark blue at the same level, so we'll be worse at distinguishing those shades than Russian-speakers who have the categories of "sinij" and "goluboj".

However, the evidence doesn't go much further than that. The strong version of the hypothesis is the one which shows up in fiction all over the place, most prominently in Orwell's "Nineteen Eighty-Four". And simple experiments can show that it's nonsense. Humans simply don't think in words. The fact that you can get caught with a thought "on the tip of your tongue", with the thought fully formed but unable to be articulated, shows that your thoughts exist independently from the words describing them.

As far as an "accurate understanding of reality" goes, I personally don't believe the evidence is nearly strong enough to suggest any such thing. But you might look into Lojban, a logical and unambiguous language that was constructed to see whether it would improve people's thinking.

P.S. Your comment on tenses deserves a bit more clarification.

English, for example, has only two *morphological* tenses: past and non-past ("walked", "walk"). All other tenses are formed by adding in other words ("will walk", "was walking"). Adherents of strong Sapir-Whorf might suggest this means English-speakers can't think about the future, whereas a Latin-speaker would. But English certainly does have ways to talk about the future! You just need to add other words for it.

The same is true for other languages. Mandarin doesn't change the verb words in any way to indicate tense. But Mandarin-speakers can certainly talk about time without any difficulty. The difference is less in what languages *can* express, and more in what they *must* express: tense in English, aspect in Ancient Greek, politeness level in Japanese, and so on.